# how to read csv rows and compare it with a my list

Tags: python

Suppose, we have a list of `listdata = [23, 511, 62]` and we want to check whether this list exist in a `csv` file and find out the name of the person who matches it

#### for e.g. csv file:

> ```
> name,age,height,weight
> bob,24,6,82
> ash,23,511,62
> mary,22,62,55
> ```

How can we do so by reading it into memory using `csv.DictReader` and checking the information if it matches print out it's name

I don't know how can I compare the whole `listdata` variable with the values in dictionary (`csv.DictReader`) as only way I know how to use dictionaries is by accessing them with key and key here is pretty limited as it can't take the whole list and compare with other keys in a same line/row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import csv

listdata = [23, 511, 62]

with open('file.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'))

    # we remove the first row because it contains headers
    for row in reader[1:]:
        row = list(row)
        if listdata == row[1:]:
            print(row[0])
            break
```

Comment: Not sure why it gives me this error
TypeError: '_csv.reader' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Did you replace `csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')` with `list(csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|'))`

Comment: Oh now I did, actually I need to keep the header intact as it is. Otherwise in my actual program I won't be able to use it with len function for division later in my code. With your code the line becomes one so len returns 1.